# pointer to int conversion compiler trouble?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, type-conversion, declaration

So I'm using Xcode to write a few tiny Objective-C apps and I have the line of code:

```
  int * foo;
    foo = 5;
    NSLog(@"does it work... %i", foo);
```

Now it compiles and runs just fine, but I was wondering, why does it give me the warning, "Incompatible integer to pointer assigning..."? I thought the code above tells it to set whatever foo is pointing to to 5, not to set the pointer itself to 5. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 4):

This piece of code works by accident: the `int` pointer happens to have sufficient space to hold an integer value, and `NSLog` reinterprets the pointer as an integer, but the program is still incorrect.

A pointer to `int` should be assigned an address of an integer variable, like this:

```
int *foo;
int var;
foo = &var;
```

Now you can assign the variable through the pointer:

```
*foo = 5;
```

You can also read the value through the pointer or through the variable:

```
NSLog(@"%d %d", *foo, var);
```